# All relations which are symmetric and anti-symmetric

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, symmetry

Describe the set of relations on $\mathbb{Z}$ which are both symmetric and anti-symmetric. Hint: this set is infinite and contains one relation with which you are already familiar.

I know that this is clearly talking about the equality relation, but what I am confused about is what does a set of relations mean if there is only one relation? Wouldn't the relation just be $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x=y\}$? Or does the set of relations mean the powerset of $S$?

Comment: How do you know there is only one such relation?

Comment: The *hint* means there are *infinitely many* relations that has both properties, and that you should be familiar with *at least one* example of such.

Comment: A set of one thing is a set of one thing.  That's true if it's a set of relations or a set of elephants.  So you are told you have an infinite set of elephants.  You figure that one of the elephants is Babar.  S ne {Babar} because S is infinite.  But {Babar} subset of S.  And S = {Babar,other elephant, third elephant,.....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, it is the power set of $S$, namely:
$$
\mathcal P(S) = \{\{(x, x) \mid x \in A\} \mid A \subseteq \mathbb Z\}
$$

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that $S$ is the relation denoting equality. However note that any subset of $S$ is also a relation that is symmetric and antisymmetric. The idea here is that we do not need to define all the integers to be equal to each other.

Thus the answer you are looking for is the set of all subsets of $S$ (which is infinite).

Answer (score 2):

The identity/equality relation *is* both anti-symmetric and symmetric.   However it is not the only such.   The empty relation *is also* both anti-symmetric and symmetric.   There are many others.

You wish to describe *all* relations (on the integers) which have the properties of both symmetry and anti-symmetry.   What are these properties and identify *how* may a relation possess both?

A relation $R$ on set $\Bbb Z$ is symmetric when ....

A relation $R$ on set $\Bbb Z$ is anti-symmetric when ....

Therefore a relation $R$ on set $\Bbb Z$ is both anti-symmetric and symmetric when ....